# Environment specific SQL Linked Server and Synonym definitions

Tags: liquibase

We are trying to use Liquibase for SQL Server and have a question regarding Contexts and Labels.  When deploying to our Dev, TST, and Prod environments, we make use of sql server synonyms and linked servers that are env specific.  For example, when deploying to TST, the Linked Server and Synonym will point to SERVER_A, but Prod should point to SERVER_B.  Is there a way for Liquibase to automatically swap in the correct SERVER value depending on which environment we are deploying to at release time?

Answer (score 0):

The Liquibase features that are used to support this are [labels, contexts](http://www.liquibase.org/2014/11/contexts-vs-labels.html), and [changelog parameters](http://www.liquibase.org/documentation/changelog_parameters.html). You might have something like this in your changelog:

```
<databaseChangeLog
        xmlns="http://www.liquibase.org/xml/ns/dbchangelog"
        xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
        xmlns:ext="http://www.liquibase.org/xml/ns/dbchangelog-ext"
        xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.liquibase.org/xml/ns/dbchangelog http://www.liquibase.org/xml/ns/dbchangelog/dbchangelog-3.5.xsd
        http://www.liquibase.org/xml/ns/dbchangelog-ext http://www.liquibase.org/xml/ns/dbchangelog/dbchangelog-ext.xsd">

    <property name="linked.server" value="SERVER_A" context="TST"/>
    <property name="linked.server" value="SERVER_B" context="Prod"/>

    <changeSet id="1" author="Brian">
         <sql>CREATE LINKED SERVER STATEMENT SO LINKED SERVER IS ${linked.server}</sql>
    </changeSet>
</databaseChangeLog>
```

I don't know the Sql Server syntax for creating what you want, so that example isn't completely correct, but the main thing is that you can use the variable reference `${linked.server}` in there. There isn't a built-in Liquibase refactoring for SQL Server Synonyms or Linked Servers, so you can either use the `<sql>` tag or write your own Liquibase extension that implements a new `<synonym>` and/or `<linkedServer>` tag.

When you run `liquibase update` you would supply the argument

`--context=TST` or `--context=Prod`

and the appropriate value would be substituted.